# Need a little help to find a pattern in a string

Tags: powershell

I am reading an XML file that contains a range of versions for an example:
[image]
8.6.22.0-8.6.24.999

My goal is to know if each one of the entries contains a range only for 8.6.22*-8.6.22* and does not contain version 8.6.21/3/4 in any place in the string.
I don't care if after the dot there are numbers (8.6.22.000, 8.6.22.999)
I tried to do it, its working for (8.6.20.0-8.6.22.999 or 8.6.1000.0000-8.6.4000.9999) but not for (8.6.22.0-8.6.24.999)

This is part of my code:
there is a function that read all the version from the XML and fill the $versions
I run in a loop for each one of the versions and compare to 8.6.22*

```
$compareversion = "8.6.22*"
if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($versions)) {
    Write-host "Versions range (Manifest):"   
    foreach ($v in $versions) {
    
        if ($v -notlike $compareversion) {
            Write-host $v -ForegroundColor Red
        
        }
        else {
            Write-host $v
               
        }  
    }
    Write-Host
}
```

The output is:

```
Versions range (Manifest):
8.6.22.607-8.6.22.999
8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999999
8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999999
8.6.22.607-8.6.22.999
8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999
8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999
8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999
8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999
8.6.22.0-8.6.24.99999999
8.6.22.0000-8.6.22.9999
8.6.22.0000-8.6.22.9999
8.6.1000.0000-8.6.4000.9999
8.6.22.607-8.6.22.999
8.6.22.000-8.6.24.999
8.6.22.000-8.6.22.999
8.6.22.1-8.6.22.9999
8.6.22.0000-8.6.22.9999
8.6.22.1-8.6.22.9999
8.6.20.0-8.6.22.999
8.6.22.001-8.6.22.999
```

Comment: Try not to use images, could you replace the output with the text? [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Version` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-7.0) to help you compare the beginning and end ranges from each line. Since this class implements [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-7.0), it makes it really easy to check if a version is a above or below the target range.

Assuming all these ranges are stored in `$allRanges`:

```bash
$allRanges | ForEach-Object {
    $start, $end = [version[]] $_.Split('-')
    if($start -ge '8.6.22' -and $end -lt '8.6.23') {
        return Write-host "In Range: $_" -ForegroundColor Green
    }

    Write-Host "Out of Range: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

The result using this code is:

```
In Range: 8.6.22.607-8.6.22.999
In Range: 8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999999
In Range: 8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999999
In Range: 8.6.22.607-8.6.22.999
In Range: 8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999
In Range: 8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999
In Range: 8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999
In Range: 8.6.22.0-8.6.22.999
Out of Range: 8.6.22.0-8.6.24.99999999
In Range: 8.6.22.0000-8.6.22.9999
In Range: 8.6.22.0000-8.6.22.9999
Out of Range: 8.6.1000.0000-8.6.4000.9999
In Range: 8.6.22.607-8.6.22.999
Out of Range: 8.6.22.000-8.6.24.999
In Range: 8.6.22.000-8.6.22.999
In Range: 8.6.22.1-8.6.22.9999
In Range: 8.6.22.0000-8.6.22.9999
In Range: 8.6.22.1-8.6.22.9999
Out of Range: 8.6.20.0-8.6.22.999
In Range: 8.6.22.001-8.6.22.99
```